# Google Map API gives Null Pointer Exception on android 5+

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to get the location of the user from `location api` of android. I have written following lines of code to get the `latitude and longitude` and then send the data to some other activity via Intent.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, this);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

     location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    try{
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition));
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I got 1 error, when I run on android 5+ device I get Null pointer Exception on each line from getting latitude variable. But for other android sdks Null pointer exception does not appear also.

**And also the marker is not visible** So I think this is the where NPE comes into picture. But I don't know why android 5+ gives this behaviour. I have compiled this app using android 6.

So for this purpose I have written code in `try catch block` and added NPE.

Why this is causing error? I am not able to figure it out. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @BijuParvathy Its not Working

Comment: `If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.`